# Set value of multicolumn combobox to all columns after selecting an item?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a multicolumn combobox with 3 columns in an Access 2013 form. If I choose one of the items in the combobox, the value that it gets set to is just the value from the 1st column. Is there any way to set the value of the combobox using VBA to all 3 values, just like when you were picking it? If you can't, then how can I set the value to the 3rd columns value instead of the first?

This is what my combobox looks like:

[image]

This is what it looks like after I select the first item:

[image]

Instead of just showing "1", I want it to show "1 | 2015 | 1.1" like it does in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (except by concatenating the columns in the row source).

The displayed value after selecting an item is always the first visible column.
So to display the 3rd column, set the previous columns to width=0 (probably not what you want) or move it to the first place.

The `Value` of the combobox can be different from the displayed value, it is controlled by the `Bound column` property.

To access the other columns, use the `.Column` property. E.g. you can add a textbox after the combobox with a control source `=myComboBox.Column(2)` to show the 3rd column of the selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up changing the order in my query which was populating the combobox, so I put the value that I wanted to display as the first field returned from my query. I can accept your answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be the following

- place a label (say "Label1") above the combobox to hide it completely but its dropdown button
- place in the userform code pane the following code:

  ```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
      Dim cbIndex As Long

      With Me
          cbIndex = .ComboBox1.ListIndex
          If cbIndex = -1 Then
              .Label1.Caption = ""
          Else
              .Label1.Caption = .ComboBox1.List(cbIndex, 0) & "|" & .ComboBox1.List(cbIndex, 1) & "|" & .ComboBox1.List(cbIndex, 2) & "|"
          End If
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

this way the user will have all functionalities of the combobox while reading the whole *combined* text upon choosing one of its elements

Comment: @Michael: did you try this?